# Extracting time from NSDate in Swift

Tags: nsdate, nsuserdefaults, nsdateformatter

Right now I have an NSDate set to be stored in NSUserDefaults. When I go to retrieve that date I want to extract and format the time. Can anyone tell me how to do this in Swift?

I have:

```
punchTimes.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "punchInTime")
punchTimes.synchronize()
```

set to store date, and would like to retrieve the NSDate time  for "punchInTime"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the NSDate object from NSUserDefaults by calling `punchTimes.objectForKey("punchInTime")`

Then use NSDateFormatter class to create a String formatted the way you want it.